# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in (путь к файлу) on line 30

Tags: php

```
    <?php 

$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 



if(mb_strlen($login) < 5 || mb_strlen($login) > 90){
    echo "Недопустимая длина логина";
    exit();
}
else if(mb_strlen($name) < 5){
    echo "Недопустимая длина имени.";
    exit();
} // Проверяем длину имени 




$pass = md5($pass."thisisforhabr"); // Создаем хэш из пароля



$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register-bd');



$result1 = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
$user1 = $result1->fetch_assoc(); 

if(!empty($user1)){
    echo "Данный логин уже используется!";
    exit();
}

$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `pass`, `name`)
    VALUES('$login', '$pass', '$name')");
$mysql->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В `$result1` у вас лежит булево значение, скорее всего `false`. Видимо запрос не смог выполниться, т.к., например, некорректный.